# Stop the route when there is no file on the SFTP component

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to zip all the files on the SFTP endpoint and move it to some other location. It is working fine but if there are no files on the SFTP endpoint I need to stop the route. There is an option **sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle** on file endpoint to handle such scenario. Is there a way I can implement this scenario?

Comment: Isn't id default behavior that the route is not triggered when there are no new files?

Answer (score 0):

The (S)FTP component does inherit the options of the File2 component. Thus you should be able to use sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle there, too.